# Ruby long running process to react to queue events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails 3 app that writes certain events to a queue.

Now on the server I want to create a service that polls the queue every x seconds, and performs other tasks on a scheduled basis.

Other than creating a ruby script and running it via a cron job, are there other alternatives that are stable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although spinning up a persistent Rails-based task is an option, you may want to look at more orderly systems like [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [Starling](https://github.com/starling/starling) to manage your workload.

I'd advise against running something in `cron` since the expense of spinning up a whole Rails stack can be significant. Running it every few seconds isn't practical as the ramp-up time on Rails is usually 5-15 seconds depending on your hardware. Doing this a few times a day is usually no big deal, though.

A simple alternative is to create a work loop in a script you can engage with `runner`:

```
interval = 15.minutes
next_time = Time.now + interval

while (true)
  if (stuff_to_do?)
    do_stuff
  end

  # Figure out how much time is left before the next iteration
  delay = next_time.to_i - Time.now.to_i

  if (delay > 0)
     # If ahead of schedule, take a break
    sleep(delay)
  end
end
```

The downside to this is that the Rails stack will remain in memory as long as this background process is running, but this is a trade-off between huge CPU hits and a memory hit.

Comment: so maybe something in scala would be more effecient?

Comment: Scala is just another language. It wouldn't be more efficient to spend a large amount of time re-implementing your system in Scala just to run it in the background. If you need to strip down for memory reasons you probably want to create an environment for your background jobs that uses only ActiveRecord and not the view or controller components that won't be used. You can be very selective what modules are loaded and trim your memory footprint dramatically.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options for that, including DelayedJob and [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

Resque relies on Redis and is the solution I use all the time (and am very happy with).

Comment: In my experience, both DelayedJob and Resque (using Redis To Go) work well on Heroku.

Comment: @Steve DelayedJob does not work well with Heroku's MongoHQ offering. Will rapidly cause your MongoHQ DB to lock up. Don't think it applies here, but just as a heads up.

Comment: @Chris Have used DelayedJob with RDS on Heroku and it works fairly well.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Ryan Bates' railscast on this subject which talks about beanstalkd and the stalker wrapper for it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker

Comment: And the asciicasts link (searchable): http://asciicasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker

Answer (score 1):

To add to the possibilities here, Using a more heavy-duty queuing system like AMQP (RabbitMQ) is made easy by the 'minion' gem. Similar to beanstalkd:

https://github.com/orionz/minion

Answer (score 1):

@Blankman, you should check out http://www.simpleworker.com, it's made for things like this and takes the burden of running/scheduling/monitoring your processes off of you. And it's very stable.